# EJB container managed threading model

Tags: concurrency, multithreading, ejb-3.0, ejb

Any good source/links or concise explaination about it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The container has a thread pool and a request queue.  When a request comes in, it's added to the queue.  A listener takes the request off the queue, checks a thread out of the thread pool, and gives it the request to process.  When the process is complete, the thread goes back into the pool to await its next assignment.

When the thread pool is exhausted, requests back up in the queue until sufficient resources are available to process them.

Comment: Thank you Pascal, I especially appreciate that coming from you.  Sincerely, Duffy